# Cordova console plug-in not working

Tags: cordova

I have been stuck at this issue for quite a few days. I did add the console plugin to the project but there is no O/P on the console when I run the app.

Cordova Plugin List:

[image: Plugin List]

Code (**index.html**):

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

</head>
<body onload="testConsole()">
    <div class="app">

        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>



    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script>

    function testConsole(){

    console.log("console.log works well");
    alert("Console: Alert");

    }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I added the alert, to see if the function does work

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your code is interpreted before the plugin is loaded. The "load" event  still might happen before "deviceready" event.
You MUST execute your code that uses plugins after the event "deviceready" happens.

You can try something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
  // you code to be executed
});
```

Or you can just attach your function to another event such as a button click, so that you can try to invoke function several times by clicking)

I recommend you to read this [page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html). It explains 'deviceready' event perfectly and briefly.
Also try not to use stuff like `<body onload="">` even for testing puproses. Prefer things like `document.addEventListener(...);`

Comment: I would like to highlight that the alert is called and works fine

Comment: alert is not a feature of a plugin, so it will work anyway. But your plugins will work only after deviceready event is fired.

Comment: In addition, on my device it refuses to execute inline scripts, so I had to place it into the index.js file in the onDeviceReady function. So plugin works fine.

Comment: Majumdar, Hello)
I would be glad if You tell me whether it helped You